# Google App Engine Fetch Slow Speeds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, node.js, google-app-engine

I'm running a NodeJS Google App Engine service that retrieves a large file and sends it to a Virtual Private Server hosted on Digital Ocean or AWS. The file is about 5MB and takes up to a minute to send in some cases and often times out. Sending the same file from a client running on on my machine, a VPS, or my teammates computer takes less then 5 seconds. After further investigation I discovered that any outgoing request from a Google App Engine instance caps at about 100-200kps regardless of destination. I have not been able to find any information indicating this is something enforced by google.

Is App Engine Capping it? How do I improve the speeds?

Comment: Are you performing the request from the same region? Take into consideration that the distance could come into latency

Comment: @KevinQuinzel Requests are both made and received in us-central. Requests made from my machine are coming from Toronto Area.

Answer (score 1):

By reviewing some resources I'd say that you might be affected by this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/64458939), it seems to happen that the custom domains add significant latency when using App Engine.

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@sachinkagarwal/public-cloud-inter-region-network-latency-as-heat-maps-134e22a5ff19) with some useful insights over the RTT behavior between regions/cloud providers, and it looks like the responses as you have pointed should be faster.

Comment: I appreciate the help @sergiofranco. While this has helped me understand a bit more, I don't think this is the issue as I still have problems when using the app engine without custom domains.

Comment: What about if you create a VM on AWS and perform a mtr to googleapis.com in order to review possible network issues. This could be coming into a [Networking issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/best-practice#reporting_a_networking_issue) that is better to address with GCP support.
I think this might be happening at the dedicated load balancing that attends App Engine request, since you are using the Fetch library.